# SwiftUI image system bigger than its encompassing stack?

Tags: image, swiftui

I've included an image system into a stack. The image displayed is bigger than its encompassing stack. I could add some padding around the image to fix the problem, but I try to understand what is happening.
I've created an simple example showing the problem. This problem does not happen if I use a text instead of the image as you can see:

[image]

The code used to generate this image is:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Color.gray

            VStack(spacing: 20) {

                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "circle.grid.hex.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                .background(Color.red)

                HStack{
                    Text("Hello world!")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                .background(Color.red)

            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

I used macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and XCode 11.4.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I don't understand why the stack is smaller than the image symbol. Is there an option so that the stack encompass exactly the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Color.gray

            VStack(spacing: 20) {

                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "circle.grid.hex.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .fixedSize()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                  //  .resizable()
                       // .scaledToFill()

                }                    .background(Color.red)


                HStack{
                    Text("Hello world!")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                .background(Color.red)

            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```